# How does the "This question belongs to another SE site" work?

Tags: support

When in JSE or other cases in StackOverflow, I found questions that are off-topic and should be closed because they should be asked in the other site, I am following the flag link and the given explanations, when I am reaching at the point that this question should be asked to that X,Y,Z site... But usually the options there are minimum and usually not the ones I am looking for.

So I am wondering, how does this work and what defines which websites should be available there? And why it's not possible to select from all other SE websites?

Answer (score 1):

I've also seen this and it's rather annoying.

I assume because the site is in Beta, therefore the only site we can suggest a question be migrated to is Meta JSE.

It would be nice to have at least the mains sites:

- Stackoverflow
- SuperUser
- Serverfault

Maybe suggesting this on Meta StackExchange would be an idea